# Access Microsoft.Graph.User user principal name property - Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using Microsoft Graph v1 API to get the list of all the users in a group. Something like :

```
var groupInfo = await graphServiceClient.Groups[group].Members.Request()
                                        .GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This returns me the list of `<Microsoft.Graph.User>` objects. The only accessible property in this object seems to be Id, `OData and AdditionalData`. Is there any way I can fetch properties like `"UserPrincipalName" , "DisplayName"` ?

I don't wish to hit graph API again to get these values based on the `user ID` that I am able to access.

I tried using:

```
var groupInfo = await graphServiceClient.Groups[group].Members.Request().Select("userPrincipalName")
                                        .GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, this still seems to give the User object and not just UPN. 
Is this a bug somewhere?

Comment: When you do the second query, does the resulting User object not have the userPrincipalName populated?

Comment: Thanks @DarrelMiller It has the userPrincipalName populated but it is wrapped as  the User DirectoryObject. 
The main concern is how do I access this property inside the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upcast the DirectoryObject into it's native type to be able to access it.

```
var groupInfo = await graphServiceClient.Groups[group].Members.Request().Select("userPrincipalName")
                                        .GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

var user = groupInfo[0] as User;
```

Comment: Thanks Darrel ! 
Works fine :)